# How to clone Ubuntu 13.04 and boot - "mbr error 1 press any key to boot from floppy"

Tags: boot, 13.04, clone

I need to clone Ubuntu 13.04 that was previously tuned to 50 identical computers. I've tried to clone from source disk to another using Acronis True Image or Clonezilla. It seems that all partitions was copied but I can't boot from this copy on the target computers. On another hand, I've inserted "original" HDD to the destination computer and it didn't boot too. There is a message "mbr error 1 press any key to boot from floppy". Could UEFI or GPT HDD be a reason of this issue?

I have Ubuntu 10.10 on the old PC and if I put it to a new PC it boots with no issues. That old HDD is not GPT.

The new HDD is GPT. And Yes, source disk works on the source computer, but doesn't work on the destination computer.

Comment: Is the new HDD GPT? Please edit your question with the answer.

Comment: Seems to be a bios bug.  Does the drive work in the original computer?

Answer (score 0):

How accurately do you need to clone your installation?  Maybe you can save the
selection state of the source, using 'dpkg --get-selection', install a
stock 13.04 on the new systems, and run 'dpkg --set-selection; dselect update' or
something like that on the new systems.  [Here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/how-to-save-a-list-of-installed-packages-and-install-these-packages-later-393191/) is an article which can help you
more than I can.